# Passing headers to Otel Gateway collector from nginx

Tags: multi-tenant, otel

Brief updae on how env is configured:

We configured keycloak infront of otel gateway collector , and the primary purpose of using keycloak is to add an auth layer to otel gateway which is working perfectly fine.
We configured nginx as reverse proxy in front of keycloak , so all the entries coming to keycloak are registered in nginx logs .

What i aim to do ?

We would like to pass on some headers from nginx to otel gateway collector and from there to backend (tempo, loki &b mimir)

We see that in nginx logs , the entry of client id we are using to send data from source to Otel gateway collector .
However when configured to set Headers "X-Scope-Org-ID" in nginx conf and send it to otel gateway via it dosent work ?

Any suggestions here would be very helpful .

Configuration of Nginx running in front of KeyCloak :
Is there anything which i am missing right now ?

Have anyone tried sending "client id" in keycloak , as headers to otel gateway collector using nginx!!

As on date , we are using headers_setter extension to enable multitenancy across loki, tempo & mimir.
While it works with no issues , we are looking for an option to add authentication layer (oauth2, KeyCloak) as anyone can send the data to our gateway collectors and flood with data.

NOTE : We have already enabled authentication to Otel GW collectors  with KeyCloak in our Non multitenancy env, in order to achieve multitenancy , we used headers_setter extension where we ask our developers to send headers mapped to X-Scope-OrgID and i see that the main drawback is we use auth: "headers_setter" and cannot combine together with "oidc" , so we disabled the auth from KeyCloak